# Simple requireJS with angularJS - angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am new to requireJS, and I wanted to get a simple starter 'hello worldish' project up and running. I'm missing something though, because I get `angular is not defined` as a JS error when the `GreetCtrl` tries to load.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ReqApp" ng-controller="GreetCtrl">
  <body>
    <h1>{{greeting}}!</h1>
    <script src="assets/require/require.js" data-main="assets/require/main"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
require.config({
    // alias libraries paths
  paths: {
    'domReady':      'domReady',
    'angular':       '../../vendor/angular/angular.min',
    'GreetCtrl':     '../../src/app/modules/GreetCtrl',
    'app':           '../../src/app/app'
  },
  // angular does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
  shim: {
    'angular': {
      exports: 'angular'
    }
  },
  // kick start application
  deps: ['./bootstrap']
});
```

bootstrap.js:

```
define([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'app'
], function (require, ng) {
    'use strict';

    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        ng.bootstrap(document, ['ReqApp']);
    });
});
```

app.js:

```
define([
  'angular',
  'GreetCtrl'
], function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  return ng.module('ReqApp', [
    'ReqApp.GreetCtrl'
  ]);
});
```

and finally, GreetCtrl.js:

```
angular.module( 'ReqApp.GreetCtrl', [])
.controller( 'GreetCtrl', function GreetCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = "greetings puny human";
});
```

According to firebug, line 1 of `GreetCtrl.js` throws an error of `angular is not defined`. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not told the `GreetCtrl` that it depends upon `angular` thus it is `undefined`.  Try changing the `GreetCtrl` to be like this

```
define(['angular'], function(angular){
    angular.module( 'ReqApp.GreetCtrl', [])
    .controller( 'GreetCtrl', function GreetCtrl ($scope) {
         $scope.greeting = "greetings puny human";
    });
});
```