# Load dependency using require

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, color-picker

I'm building an app using AngularJS.  The environment already has several modules embedded in it, some of which I'm loading fine using require.  I'm trying to add a novel one, and I can't get the steps right.

The module is color-picker.js: https://github.com/Alberplz/angular-colorpicker-directive

This is what I am trying, but not sure where to add the dependency.  If I add it to the array in that first argument, I get "Reference error: angular not defined".  I thought require() was supposed to resolve dependencies first before executing code.

```
<script>
    require(['angular', './js/color-picker.js', 'components/shared/index'], function (angular) {
        var app = angular.module('app', ['colorpicker']);

        app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.var3 = '#ff2e00';
            $scope.var4 = '#e6ff00';
            $scope.var5 = '#db00ff';
            $scope.var6 = '#1fd27f';
            $scope.var7 = '#008fff';
            $scope.var8 = '#ff2e00';
            $scope.var9 = '#e6ff00';
        }]);
    });
</script>
```

This next code works, but I do need to load other modules that pertain to this environment to get other components of the app working.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color-picker.min.css" />  

<script src="/scripts/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/color-picker.min.js"></script>
<script>var app = angular.module('app', ['colorpicker']);</script>  
<script>
    app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.var3 = '#ff2e00';
        $scope.var4 = '#e6ff00';
        $scope.var5 = '#db00ff';
        $scope.var6 = '#1fd27f';
        $scope.var7 = '#008fff';
        $scope.var8 = '#ff2e00';
        $scope.var9 = '#e6ff00';
    }]);
</script>
```

I'm a require() noob and don't understand how to tell require that this new module is dependent on Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
 <script>
        require(['angular', './js/color-picker.js', 'components/shared/index'], function (angular,colorpicker, index) {
            var app = angular.module('app', ['colorpicker']);

        app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.var3 = '#ff2e00';
            $scope.var4 = '#e6ff00';
            $scope.var5 = '#db00ff';
            $scope.var6 = '#1fd27f';
            $scope.var7 = '#008fff';
            $scope.var8 = '#ff2e00';
            $scope.var9 = '#e6ff00';
        }]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No dice.  I get that `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at color-picker.js:9`

Comment: can you share little more of the error log, if you have

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575410/simple-requirejs-with-angularjs-angular-is-not-defined

Comment: This got me on the right path. Thank you so much. The environment has a call to require.config() higher up in the page, and once I added another path and its dependency, it worked. Angular is pulled in with that earlier call, so this works.  I'm posting the full-ish code as a new answer.

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't control the whole page, I didn't realize that other dependencies were loading via an earlier call to require.config().  This is what got it all to work together.

```
<script>
    require.config({
        paths: {            
            'colorpicker': './js/color-picker.min'
        },
        shim: {         
            'colorpicker': {
                deps: ['angular']
            }
        }       
    }); 

    require(['angular', 'underscore', 'colorpicker'], function (angular, _) {       
        var app = angular.module('app', ['colorpicker']);
    });
</script>
```